# Trouble using DC.js (crossfilter and d3 convenience library) - bar chart not showing values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter, dc.js

I am using this library: [Dimensional Charting](http://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/) to build some relatively standard charts that need CrossFilter functionality.

I have been following the examples but they aren't working for me.

Here is my code:

```
var dashData = crossfilter(data.report),
dataByHour = dashData.dimension(function(d){ return d3.time.hour(new Date(d.timestamp))}),
totalByHour = dataByHour.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.amount }),

dc.barChart("#graphTimeOverview")
    .width(990) // (optional) define chart width, :default = 200
    .height(250) // (optional) define chart height, :default = 200
    .transitionDuration(500) // (optional) define chart transition duration, :default = 500
    .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 40})
    .dimension(dataByHour) // set dimension
    .group(totalByHour) // set group
    .elasticY(true)
    .centerBar(true)
    .gap(1)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([new Date(data.report[0].timestamp), new Date(data.report[(data.report.length - 1)].timestamp)]))
    .round(d3.time.hour.round)
    .xUnits(d3.time.hours)
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true);

dc.renderAll();
```

I know the crossfilter data is working correctly, here is a sample of the group:

```
totalByHour:

[ {key:(new Date(1361746800000)), value:6170.17},
  {key:(new Date(1361678400000)), value:3003},
  {key:(new Date(1361581200000)), value:2350.42}, 
  {key:(new Date(1361667600000)), value:1636.19},
    etc... 
]
```

Unfortunately all this gets me is an empty graph, it seems to compute the y-axis correctly, so it would seem to me that it can read the data, however I never see any bar values:

[image]

Comment: Also just to add in case anyone would ask: There are no SVG elements which represent the bars in the DOM, so its not a styling/visual issue.

Comment: Can you build a jsFiddle?

Comment: There is not enough data on your question to know what's going wrong. Like that I would recommend you to use the Chrome javascript console to see if there is an error message.

Comment: I agree, I have also done everything I can this is as much information as I know. At this point I have given up on DC.js and I will just implement my graphs in D3 and CrossFilter natively.

Comment: My point was more to ask you to setup a jsFiddle with what you have for now in order for us to help you on your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the `data.report` array is not sorted by timestamp (the sample provided is unsorted). In your code, you assume that those values are sorted. You can try using

```
// Compute the timestamp extent
var timeExtent = d3.extent(data.report, function(d) { return d.timestamp; });

dc.barChart("#graphTimeOverview")
    // more settings here
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain(timeExtent.map(function(d) { return new Date(d); })))
    .round(d3.time.hour.round)
    .xUnits(d3.time.hours)
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true);
```

It would be easier to tell what is the problem if you provide a jsFiddle.

Comment: My group was not sorted by x-domain!

Answer (score 0):

I started using dc.js few days ago, so I don't know for sure. But, I think your code should go in

`d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) { //your-code };`
or
`d3.json("data.json", function(data) {//your-code};`
or
`jQuery.getJson("data.json", function(data){//your-code});`

Comment: Those are all means of asynchronously retrieving some data format and converting to an object array. I already have my data in an object array (dashData) which is loaded into Crossfilter which is what handles the data from then on, in principle anyways.